# LaTeX \usepackage{forest} not working, apparently due to .sty file?

Tags: package, latex, pdflatex, miktex

I am trying to use the TeX package forest to draw a simple tree diagram. However, the package does not want to be used for some reason. I have tried installing from two different mirrors, and manually from the CTAN website, and still doesn't work. The line causing the error is `\usepackage{forest}`, as the file compiles fine without this line. According to the log below, the error is with the `forest.sty` file itself, however no one else seems to be having this issue - unless its due to a new TeX update?

Anyone have any idea as to what is going on here?

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\unhbox
l.1061 }
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.1061 }
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! Extra \endcsname.
\pgf@arrow@letter@ ...l@arrow@name@end \endcsname
#1
l.1061 }
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
...
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\unhbox
l.1087 \csdef{forestmath@convert@from@n@to@_}
#1{\unexpanded{#1}}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\unhbox
l.1088 \csdef{forestmath@convert@from@d@to@_}
#1{\unexpanded{#1}}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
...
```

This goes on for a while, on lines ranging from 1061-6309. The error list shows many lines similar to this:

```
C:\...tex/latex/forest/forest.sty | Error line 1087 !Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again>\unhbox ...
```

The `forest.sty` file on lines 1086-8 are

```
1086: \def\forestmathzero{\forestmath@convert@from\forestmathtype@count{0}}
1087: \csdef{forestmath@convert@from@n@to@_}#1{\unexpanded{#1}}
1088: \csdef{forestmath@convert@from@d@to@_}#1{\unexpanded{#1}}
```

**Edit:** As answered below, the problem is the package `underscore`, i.e. the line `\usepackage[strings]{underscore}`. A minimal example of this is therefore

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[strings]{underscore}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
This won't work
\end{document}
```

Comment: please make a compilable [mre] and show your complete .log file so we can see which versions of the kernel and packages you use.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}` works fine for me

Comment: After trying to make a minimal example, it turns out the error is caused by the package `underscore` when combined with `forest`. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the conflicting package is `underscore`, i.e. the line `\usepackage[strings]{underscore}`. Removing this line solves the problem.

Comment: you could also invert the order in which you load  the packages